# [SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.]

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, connection

Deployed a site to Windows 7, works fine. Now I do the same for Windows 2008 R2 (SP1) and it fails to login. Under Windows 7, in SQL Server 2012, I added the user IIS APPPOOL/DefaultAppPool and made it db_owner. The same trick doesn't work under Windows 2008 R2 (with IIS7 and SQL Server 2012).
What might be wrong? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What helps is to set the Process Model Identity to LocalSystem. Is that the solution? If so in IIS right click DefaultAppPool, select advanced settings and under Process Model modify the Identity...

Comment: First things first. Are the DB and the worker process located on the same machine?  If so, bring up the login's properties page and choose the "Status" menu item on the left. Ensure that permissions to connect are set to "Grant" and login is "Enabled."